# JQUERY script API links added for full calendar in html gives get 404 not found error

Tags: jquery, html, django, fullcalendar

Following are the API links i have added in html:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' /> 
<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'>      </script>
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
```

But it gives 404 not found error.
   I have the Fullcalendar folder in my project.
   The path:
     F:\RESUME_MANAGEMENT_19_02_2014\Vamsi_19_02_14_latest\mysite\template_html\fullcalendar-
       2.0.1\fullcalendar-2.0.1
     has fullcalendar.js file and other folders and files.

Here the structure of MY folder look like:

- mysite

  - template_html

    - SEARCH.HTML
    - fullcalendar-2.0.1

      - fullcalendar-2.0.1

        - fullcalendar.css
        - fullcalendar.js

    Please tell me where I am going wrong ?

Comment: In which file you calling this .js file and where it located?

Comment: I am calling .JS  and .CSS files in "Search.html"  which is located in template_html folder.

Answer (score 2):

Let say your has `main file` (e.g: index.html) is on this path:

`F:/RESUME_MANAGEMENT_19_02_2014/Vamsi_19_02_14_latest/mysite/index.html`

- Please note `index.html` is file you are using to call other `JS` and `CSS` file

And here is example for your `fullcalendar.css` file path:

`F:/RESUME_MANAGEMENT_19_02_2014/Vamsi_19_02_14_latest/mysite/template_html/fullcalendar-2.0.1/fullcalendar-2.0.1/fullcalendar.css`

Last one is example for your `fullcalendar.js` file path:

`F:/RESUME_MANAGEMENT_19_02_2014/Vamsi_19_02_14_latest/mysite/template_html/fullcalendar-2.0.1/fullcalendar-2.0.1/fullcalendar.js`

So your code in `index.html` might be something like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='template_html/fullcalendar-2.0.1/fullcalendar-2.0.1/fullcalendar.css' /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src='template_html/fullcalendar-2.0.1/fullcalendar-2.0.1/fullcalendar.js'></script>
```

Here the structure of your folder look like:

```
- mysite
  - index.html  
  - template_html  
     - fullcalendar-2.0.1  
         - fullcalendar-2.0.1
              - fullcalendar.css
              - fullcalendar.js
```

Comment: I am calling .JS and .CSS files in "Search.html" which is located in template_html folder.I have tried your suggested solution, but it does not seem to work. ERROR seen example: GET http://192.168.1.223:1234/query/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css 404 (NOT FOUND) CODE:<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<script type="text/javascript" src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script><script type="text/javascript" src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script> The error can be seen for rest scripts too.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is tell Django where your static files are by adding this to your settings.py:
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "/path/to/your/project/staticfiles/",
)

by static files i mean your js and css

then add this on top of your template:
{% load staticfiles %}

and declare your tags like this:

```
<link href="{% static 'js/jquery.datatables/bootstrap-adapter/css/datatables.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Actually I am new to Django. Can you please tell little more in details about staticfiles in settings.py! In my settings.py only:::  STATIC_URL = '/static/'.   I  can see regarding static file ! Thanks for reply !

Comment: read this documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

Comment: and you have to add the extra line STATICFILES_DIRS = ( "/path/to/your/project/staticfiles/", ) below your  STATIC_URL

Comment: Well ! I am late to reply ! Apologies! But, things are still not working well ! I am now trying to make a custom calendar ! I hope it works ! Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this is you folder structure.

```
-mysite
  -template_html
    -search.html
    -fullcalendar-2.0.1
      -fullcalendar-2.0.1
        -fullcalendar.css
        -fullcalendar.js
```

Just change fullcalendar-2.0.1 folder names to fullcalendar and for both folders
and the path is

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' /> 
<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
```

Comment: I have tried your suggested solution ! Still the same error !

Comment: can you post the folder structure for you .js. .css file search.html files

Comment: please see my POST again, i have edited the folder structure there. Thanks !

Comment: YA ! I tried but ERROR: GET http://192.168.1.223:1234/query/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css 404 (NOT FOUND)   like this can be seen for other scripts too.

Comment: have you changed the folder name in the folder structure. if you changed then check for the full path.
here what is meant by query?
if 192.168.1.223:1234/query/ - renders your mysite folder then check the path and you should change the .css and .js path to template_html/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js and template_html/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css

Comment: query is function defined in views.py. And yes my .css and .js files are in correct path.

Comment: then the problem is with you url generator.
actually the path should be like this
http://localhost/yoursitename/template_html/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js
But your url is going worng location. check it.

Comment: U mean urls.py ?? Can you tell me a bit about it. Actually I am new to django. And that complicated URLs i still don't know how to write and map. THANKS !!

Comment: Well ! I am late to reply ! Apologies! But, things are still not working well ! I am now trying to make a custom calendar ! I hope it works ! Thanks for help !